# FreeBSD password file

Tags: linux, freebsd, password-management, bsd, shadow-copy

What would be FreeBSD password file equivalent of linux /etc/shadow and /etc/passwd? Is it the same?

According to what I heard /etc/passwd exists in FreeBSD, but not sure in case of /etc/shadow.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This information should be explained under the *Files* section of `man passwd`

Comment: This [RTFM answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98959/rtfm-like-answers-flag-them-or-allow-them) is not helpful as it does not provide an answer.

Answer (score 6):

In freeBSD password and user related information are stored as blow.

```
 /etc/master.passwd  the user database. Its equivalent for /etc/shadow of Linux
 /etc/passwd         a Version 7 format password file. Same as /etc/passwd of Linux
 /etc/passwd.XXXXXX  temporary copy of the password file
```

Comment: `/etc/spwd.db` is a cache of `/etc/master.passwd`, so if you edit the latter, you have to run `pwd_mkdb -p /etc/master.passwd` afterwards. (You're better off using `vipw` though.) More detail here: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pwd_mkdb#end